# RxJava: how to make "generate" operator emit infinite stream lazily to downstream "concatMap"

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I wonder why the `generate` operator in the snippet below causes *tons* of "received X" lines be printed between "fetched a page". Documentation suggests that *downstream* will ask emitter to emit and `concatMap` should ask for the next value upon completion of inner source (I guess). Any idea how can I make generate not eager in this scenario?

```kotlin
  Observable
    .generate(
      { 0 },
      BiFunction { s: Int, emitter: Emitter<Int> -> emitter.onNext(s); s + 1 }
    )
    .doOnNext { println("received $it") }
    .concatMapSingle { page ->
      Single
        .just(if (page == 3) emptyList() else listOf(page))
        .delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    .doOnNext { println("fetched a page") }
    .takeWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }
    .blockingSubscribe()
```

This prints

```
received 1
received 2
...
received 1000
fetched page
received 1001
received 1002
...
received 3000
fetched page
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RxJava2, [The `Observable` class does not support backpressure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#backpressure), which means you can't control the rate of emission of upstream operators. Use `Flowable` instead, you should see the behavior you expect.

Comment: Hm, but why does documentation of `Observable.generate()` say: "generator — the Function called with the current state whenever a particular downstream Observer has requested a value". Is this a documentation bug then?

Comment: @dimsuz Yes, I think so. In RxJava3 the wording is changed to "the Consumer called in a loop after a downstream Observer has subscribed."

Comment: The wording was changed in [this PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6831), which removed all mentions of "downstream requesting" items from the Observable class